# building custom image classification model not working

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit, image-classification, tflite

I am training an image classification model in a flutter application using the google ml_kits' custom model function.

I have tried using 'TensorFlow Lite Model Maker' but it didn't work due to the import and compatibility issues they are experiencing. I also tried using keras to create a model and convert to tensorflow lite but couldn't add metadata to it because of tflite-support dependency incompatibilities all on either colab or my personal workspace with different python virtual environments. Most of the tutorials out there just don't seem to work anymore. Is there anyway to do this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.